Sympy limit raises Value and Syntaxerror
This is my code
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x',positive=True ,real=True)
h=symbols('h', positive=True, real=True)
expr=input('Enter the expression: ')
expr2=expr.replace('x','(x+h)')
actualexp=f"(({expr2})-({expr}))/{h}"
print(limit(actualexp,h,0))

As you see im trying to take a derivative using sympy's limit function, but this raises a Valueerror and a Syntax errorValueError:
Error from parse_expr with transformed code: "((Integer (2 )(Symbol ('x' )+Symbol ('h' )))-(Integer (2 )Symbol ('x' )))/Symbol ('h' )"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\FAKENAME\Desktop\derivative.py", line 6, in <module>
    actualexp= parse_expr(f"(({expr2})-({expr}))/{h}")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\FAKENAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 1087, in parse_expr
    raise e from ValueError(f"Error from parse_expr with transformed code: {code!r}")
  File "C:\Users\FAKENAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 1078, in parse_expr
    rv = eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\FAKENAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 906, in eval_expr
    expr = eval(
           ^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 1
    ((Integer (2 )(Symbol ('x' )+Symbol ('h' )))-(Integer (2 )Symbol ('x' )))/Symbol ('h' )
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

i tried googling, no result

raises a Valueerror and a Syntax error. Please provide the error message along with the stack trace that is produced

What expr gives this error? 2*x can be parsed as times.  2x cannot.

Googling errors is only useful if other people have made something similar before.  Syntax errors tend to be unique, with a missing or wrong character. Googling is a poor substitute for spending time with the basic documentation - in this case for sympy.

You should parse the expression... you are actually passing a string object representing a mathematical expression to limit. You shuold parse the string to make it a true sympy object. Here how to fixed it
actualexp= parse_expr(f"(({expr2})-({expr}))/{h}")

print(limit(actualexp, h, 0).simplify())

Another example on how to parse expressions

still a Value error

cant edit because i was testing for a few minutes, some values give error, such as 2x, but values like x^2 dont give errors

the problem is that you don't show us the string you input. Parsers are designed for general purpose and have rules... but they don't read your mind. Check the link I provided for further details and reference to parameters of the parse_expr

See also How to parse expressions such as '2x'.  Note that by default, x^2 will get parsed as an XOR operation. For powers you need **.
